# How to delete all event entries from a specific calendar from Google calendar API .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying editing a tool to allow a user to select from a list of their calendars and then clear all event entries / add new ones based on Microsoft project tasks.
Heres the original tool: http://daball.github.com/Microsoft-Project-to-Google-Calendar/

I am completely unexperienced with Google APIs / the calendar API, and am having some trouble. The program I'm editing keeps track of which CalendarEntry the user has selected from a list of their calendars. What I am currently trying to do is create a EventFeed which gives me the EventEntries of that selected calendar, so I can then delete all of them. The purpose of this is to allow someone to use this tool to also update the calendar from the project file whenever changes are made. Here's my function attempting the delete.

```
 private void clearPreviousCalendarEntries(CalendarEntry calendarEntry)
    {      
        EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
        query.Uri = new Uri(calendarEntry.Links[0].AbsoluteUri);

        EventFeed feed = (EventFeed)calendarService.Query(query);

        AtomFeed batchFeed = new AtomFeed(feed);

        foreach (EventEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            entry.Id = new AtomId(entry.EditUri.ToString());
            entry.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(GDataBatchOperationType.delete);
            batchFeed.Entries.Add(entry);
        }

        EventFeed batchResultFeed = (EventFeed)calendarService.Batch(batchFeed, new Uri(feed.Batch));

        foreach (EventEntry entry in batchResultFeed.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 200 && entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 201)
                this.listBoxResults.SelectedIndex = this.listBoxResults.Items.Add("Problem deleteing " + entry.Title.Text + " error code: " + entry.BatchData.Status.Code);
            else
                this.listBoxResults.SelectedIndex = this.listBoxResults.Items.Add("Deleted " + entry.Title.Text);
        }

    }
```

My feed doesn't return the results I was hoping for, but to be honest I'm not sure how to request the events correctly.

`query.Uri = new Uri(calendarEntry.Links[0].AbsoluteUri);` is something I grabbed from the portion of the program which is adding event to a specific calendar

`AtomEntry insertedEntry = calendarService.Insert(new Uri(calendarEntry.Links[0].AbsoluteUri), eventEntry);`

These posts are definitely related to what I'm looking for but I haven't arrived at a solution

- [google-calendar-get-events-from-a-specific-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019517/google-calendar-get-events-from-a-specific-calendar)
- [how can i retrieve a event exclusive from a calendar that i created (not default one)?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=2e8b8003b1aa5fd9&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
            CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("your calendar name");
            myService.setUserCredentials(username, password);

            CalendarEntry calendar;

            try
            {
                calendar = (CalendarEntry)myService.Get(http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full/45kk8jl9nodfri1qgepsb65fnc%40group.calendar.google.com);
                foreach (AtomEntry item in calendar.Feed.Entries)
                {
                    item.Delete();
                }
            }
            catch (GDataRequestException)
            {
            }
```

You can find "Calendar ID" (something like this: 45kk8jl9nodfri1qgepsb65fnc%40group.calendar.google.com) from Calendar Details page inside Google Calendar.

this is a related post:

[google calendar api asp.net c# delete event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963461/735864)

this is a useful doc:

http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: In your example, calendar.Feed.Entries does not give EventEntries, it gives CalendarEntries.

Comment: I also probably should've been stated it outright, but I was going for a solution where I could query for the EventEntries based on an already existing CalendarEntry, instead of using a specific ID gathered from within Google Calendar

Answer (score 0):

A way I eventually arrived at was gathering the calendarID from the URI of the calendar, and then creating a new EventQuery using that id. Here's the new version of the code above

```
private void clearPreviousCalendarEntries(CalendarEntry calendarEntry)
    {
        this.listBoxResults.SelectedIndex = this.listBoxResults.Items.Add("Clearing previous calender entries");

        String calendarURI = calendarEntry.Id.Uri.ToString();
        //The last part of the calendarURI contains the calendarID we're looking for
        String calendarID = calendarURI.Substring(calendarURI.LastIndexOf("/")+1);

        EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
        query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + calendarID + "/private/full");

        EventFeed eventEntries = calendarService.Query(query);

        AtomFeed batchFeed = new AtomFeed(eventEntries);

        foreach (AtomEntry entry in eventEntries.Entries)
        {
            entry.Id = new AtomId(entry.EditUri.ToString());
            entry.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(GDataBatchOperationType.delete);

            batchFeed.Entries.Add(entry);
        }

        EventFeed batchResultFeed = (EventFeed)calendarService.Batch(batchFeed, new Uri(eventEntries.Batch));

        //check the return values of the batch operations to make sure they all worked.
        //the insert operation should return a 201 and the rest should return 200
        bool success = true;
        foreach (EventEntry entry in batchResultFeed.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 200 && entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 201)
            {
                success = false;
                listBoxResults.SelectedIndex = listBoxResults.Items.Add("The batch operation for " +
                    entry.Title.Text + " failed.");
            }
        }

        if (success)
        {
            listBoxResults.SelectedIndex = listBoxResults.Items.Add("Calendar event clearing successful!");
        }

    }
```

I'm not particular happy with this, it seems odd to use string manipulation to gather the info and chop together my own query. But it works and I have been struggling to find a way to get this done.